# What kind of syntax diagrams are these, found in a book on legal writing?

Tags: syntax, terminology

These don't look like syntax trees in undergrad linguistics syntax textbooks. Do linguists use these diagrams? What are they called?

Page 343.

> Diagrams for grammatical analysis are visual aids to understanding sentence structure. The following diagrams reflect a conventional method of “mapping” parts of speech. Reviewing these diagrams should assist writers in identifying the true Subject, Verb, and Object in their sentences. Only with a clear understanding of Subjects, Verbs, and Objects and how they interrelate can a writer produce clear and direct sentences.
>
> A MICROGRAMMAR

Page 347.

> 3. Complex Sentence
>
> i. The race will continue unless the rain ruins the track.
> ii. Until the motion is heard, the court will not rule.
>
> [image]

Bahrych, Merino. *Legal Writing and Analysis in a Nutshell 5th edition* (2017). 343.

Comment: They're called ["Reed-Kellogg diagrams"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram).

Comment: They apparently used to be taught in every US school, but are unknown in the UK (and I suspect elsewhere in the Anglosphere).

Comment: Dreadful stuff. This is what Wikipedia says about the Reed-Kellogg system: "The connections to modern principles for constructing parse trees are present in the Reed-Kellogg diagrams, although Reed and Kellogg understood such principles only implicitly". This contrasts them with modern systems, implying that they are out-of-date. The Reed-Kellogg method of "diagramming" sentences has been intellectually obsolete for a hundred years. I can't see any reason for preferring it to the modern system. Avoid it at all costs!

Comment: Like the Electoral College, there's no reason to prefer it, but it's traditional. That's why it's appearing in a legal text.